# Правильный sq update запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такие таблицы ASC: id, summa, user, name, id_match; InfoUser: id, user_id, balans.

Таблица ASC такие значения:

- id=1, summa=100, user=1, name=GG, id_match=5;
- id=2, summa=300, user=2, name=GG, id_match=5;
- id=3, summa=200, user=3, name=YY, id_match=5;
- id=4, summa=700, user=4, name=ZZ, id_match=6;
- id=5, summa=430, user=5, name=AA, id_match=6;

Таблица InfoUser:

- id=1, user_id=1, balans=0;
- id=2, user_id=2, balans=0;
- id=3, user_id=3, balans=0;
- id=4, user_id=4, balans=0;
- id=5, user_id=5, balans=0;

Нужно выбрать всех пользователей из таблицы ASC, т.е. поля user(поле user(таблица ASC)==полю user_id(таблица InfoUser)) и изменить у них поле balans(таблица InfoUser) на значение из поля summa(таблица ASC). Как сделать такой запрос?

Comment: А каким боком прикручена `Match`? чё она вообще делает в этом вопросе?

Comment: ааа.. точно.. ну она здесь не нужна вроде...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверно вам нужно будет изменить название одной из таблиц:) ASC

```
UPDATE InfoUser 
JOIN `ASC` ON `ASC`.user = InfoUser.user_id
SET InfoUser.balans = `ASC`.summa;
```

Comment: Только следует строго оговорить, что в таблице ASC поле user обязано быть уникальным. В противном случае это лотерея получится. А само имя таблицы следует обрамить бэктиками. Во избежание...